# Can we measure code performance in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dottrace

I am using IntelliJ IDE for Java application development. I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the time it takes for a particular function to complete from IntelliJ.I googled around but some mentioned about dotTrace but I couldn't really get a grasp of, if it can be linked from IntelliJ. Any links or answers if its possible is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is an IntelliJ plugin for JProfiler: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/253?pr= maybe have a look at that?

Comment: There is an IntelliJ plugin for [jmh](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7529?pr=). Use it.

Comment: dotTrace is a profiling tool for .NET applications; it does not include any Java support and cannot be used with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to calculate performance, please use nano second time and estimate precise time with that. i follow the below approach,

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// TODO - Call Function Here
long endTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Comment: OP wants this as an IntelliJ feature rather than a manual code intervention.

Comment: You can do a BenchMark using JMH if you want accurate results.